# Flutter : delete just one page from back stack

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

So, i know that this code will removes all of the routes except for the new /login.:

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

*now i want to **remove just one page** from the back stack..*

Example : To create a new group, i dislpay a 'Create new group' page that contain some information (Enter page name, Enter page category ...). On submitting we pass to the new group details..
But when i click to the back button, i don't want to return to the 'Create new group' page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pushReplacementNamed` will replace the latest one with a newly added navigator screen

**With Named:**

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');
```

**Without Named:**

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login')
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.of(context).pop()

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html)

Comment: yes, i do this now.

but, of course, i have to do  Navigator.of(context).pop() before navigate to the new page.
And this is really not very good for the user because he will see, for 'milliseconds' a page closed and other opened .. i think this is not the best way..

Comment: You can use pushAndReplace